# How to set OxyPlot origin in top left corner?

Tags: wpf, charts, axis, series, oxyplot

I create a `OxyPlot` plot with 20 series. Each `series` represents a channel. The origin is now at bottom left corner.

See picture bellow:

[image]

I would like to have them order from top to bottom. How to set OxyPlot origin in top left corner?(See picture bellow)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but you just had to set the Axis StartPosition to 1 and the EndPosition to 0

```
CategoryAxis myAxis = new CategoryAxis();
myAxis.StartPosition = 1;
myAxis.EndPosition = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a within `Oxyplot` `Axis` configuration propriety `StartPosition` that is supposed to `get` and `set` the start position of the `axis`.

[image]

However I did not figure it out if this would change the orientation of the origin point.

I came up with a different solution, I decided to plot them reversely and use a `CategoryAxis` for the left axis and set the labels in a descending order.

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    MajorTickSize = 0,
    MinorTickSize = 0
});

plotModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    Title = MyTitle,
    MajorTickSize = 0,
    MinorTickSize = 0,
    LabelField = "LabelChannels",
    Labels = 
    {   "20",
        "19",
        ...
        "3",
        "2",
        "1",
    }
});
```

It would be nice though to know if there is any other way, much simpler than what I did.